# Run the same code as before but my training set were automatically reduced to only 2.5% ( training in Google Colab)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, training-data, conv-neural-network

Previously I implemented 2 CNN models (Resnet50v2 and inceptionResNetv2) with a dataset contains 3662 images. Both worked fine in Google colab during training and validation. Now I re-run the exactly same code again and training samples per epoch were reduced to only 92 samples per epoch by itself (before it was 2929/epoch). Two models were using separate notebooks and they are both like this now.

I thought it might due to limited RAM (after 1 month of google colab, it seems reduced to half) so I upgraded to Colab pro with 25 G RAM. It doesn't solve the problem.

Has anyone got the same issue? Anyone can give a clue what could be the reason and a solution to fix it? Many thanks!

Some code in the end of the workflow here (they worked well before):

```
model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionResNetV2(
    include_top=True, weights=None, input_tensor=None, input_shape=None,
    pooling=None, classes=5)
```

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
```

```
model.fit(X, y_orig, epochs = 20, batch_size = 32, validation_split = 0.2, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think I found the reason. It was the number of batch that displayed during training. In my case: 2929(no. of train samples) / 32(batch_size) = 91.5 (number displayed now during training).

To test it, I changed the batch size to 8 and I got 366 / epoch. Also the overall training time stays the same, suggesting the number of training samples were actually staying the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using tensorflow v1 or v2?

Does this problem persist if you switch to 1.x by running a cell with `%tensorflow_version 1.x` prior to importing tensorflow?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your suggestion. You solved my problem straight way! Now it works if load tensoflow 1.0.  Before both worked in TF 2.0. Really didn't know this was the case. Big thanks to you!

Comment: Wait, but now a new problem comes up. I quickly tried both models and both cannot pass 1st epoch. Both model stuck ar 2912 of 2929 samples:

Train on 2929 samples, validate on 733 samples
Epoch 1/20
  32/2929 [..............................] - ETA: 19:48 - loss: 1.5145 - acc: 0.3125WARNING:tensorflow:Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (0.211341). Check your callbacks.
2912/2929 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.9128 - acc: 0.6762.